# Is there a way to trap object allocation in Java inside your code through a method callback?

Tags: java, optimization, memory-management, profiling, profiler

I want my application to *profile itself* and tell me where memory allocation is taking place. Profilers are able to do that, so my application should be able to do that somehow too. How do profilers trap object instantiation and how can I do it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `-javaagent` to pass instrumentation code into the JVM. We actually use [this technique](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/05/java-development-without-gc/) to find *instance leaks* in our applications. Below an example:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
String s = new String("hi");
MemorySampler.start();
queue.offer(s);
MemorySampler.end();
if (MemorySampler.wasMemoryAllocated()) MemorySampler.printSituation();
```

Outputs:

```
Memory allocated on last pass: 24576
Memory allocated total: 24576

Stack Trace:
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:327)
    TestGC.main(TestGC2.java:25)
```

Where you can see that the object allocation happens on line 327 of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

**Disclaimer:** I work for Coral Blocks which develops the `MemorySampler` class above.

Comment: Could you explain what is actually going on under the covers?  My belief is that your (proprietary) library is doing code injection.  Is that correct?

Comment: It is something supported by the JVM. The Oracle JVM supports code injection through the `-javaagent` command line option. This is the tutorial I used http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml

Comment: Where can I read more about the `MemorySampler` you describe above?

Comment: @rdalmeida can you provide link to download `MemorySampler`

Answer (score 2):

> How do profilers trap object instantiation and how can I do it myself?

Profilers typically do that by interacting with a debug agent that is monitoring what is going on inside the JVM.

However, there is no way that an application can interact with the debug agent of its own JVM.  It is not supported, and if you attempt to do it (somehow), your JVM is liable to lock up.

You may be able to get a application to profile itself is if you inject the profiling code into the bytecode files for all of the classes whose memory usage needs to be profiled.  For example, replace each "new" or "newarray" instruction with a call to a method (of the appropriate type) that creates the object / array and also does your profiling stuff.  But this is pretty tricky stuff ....